# Java Deep Clone List of Objects in Separate Thread Atomically

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, thread-safety, clone

Suppose I have an `ArrayList<Foo>`. This list is being modified very frequently. Even the values of the elements in the list will have values that change all the time. All of the modifications to this list are being performed by the main thread.

How would I go about cloning the list (deep level, elements should be cloned also) in a separate thread in such a way that it does not delay the main thread (or at least not by much), and the copied list contains a snapshot in time (I think the term is atomically) of all of the Foo objects, with there values identical to the original list (again in one snapshot of time).

Thanks in advance. I know the solution has to do with synchronization but I am at a loss in meeting all of the above criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a simple answer to this unfortunately. If the modifications being made to the list are already threadsafe, you can grab a lock on the list (or whatever you're using for synchronization), make your copy, and release the lock. You'll need to make sure that any modifications to the items themselves are using the same lock.

Alternatively, you could use immutable constructs (but you need to use this not just for the list, but for the list contents as well), then you'll never need to lock and can just grab a copy of the list at your leisure.

There are downsides and risks to both approaches. If you want a good resource, I strongly recommend [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/).

Comment: Thanks for quick response! Though I was looking for an example of some sort to get me on the right track, not a link to a book.

Comment: CopyOnWriteArrayList is certainly useful, but remember to be careful about modifying the items themselves (i.e. the foos in CopyOnWriteArrayList<Foo>); it will not save you from cross thread issues there...